# AspNetCore 6 / Unit Testing with UnserManager without Mocking it

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using AspNetCore 6 and trying to use the UserManager and RoleManager in my UnitTests.
I don't like to mock them because I want to test scenarios where I need access to different users stored in the database.
I have found a way to get to the UserManager, but then the DB context seems to be different.
I have oriented myself on [this](https://terencegolla.com/.net/unit-testing-asp-net-core-identity/)

```cs
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    internal DBContext DBContext;
    internal UserManager<ApplicationUser> AppUserManager;
    internal RoleManager<ApplicationRole> AppRoleManager;
    internal HttpContext HttpContext;
    internal IConfiguration AppConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json").Build();

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void TestSetup()
    {
        // Mock the Http Context accessor
        var mockHttpContextAccessor = MockHttpContextAccessor("MrX", "MrX");
        HttpContext = mockHttpContextAccessor.Object.HttpContext;

        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        // Add the DbContext
        serviceCollection
            .AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseOracle(AppConfiguration["OracleUnitTestDbConnection"])
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            })
            .AddSingleton(mockHttpContextAccessor.Object)
            .AddLogging()
            .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>()
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        DBContext = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<DBContext>();

        // When initializing like this it seems to get a different DBContext than the one above  
        AppUserManager = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        AppRoleManager = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();

        DBContext.Database.BeginTransaction();          // Transaction will be Rollbacked in [TestCleanup]

        MrXRole = CreateRole("MrXRole");                // Adds the ApplicationRole "MrXRole" to DBContext
        MrX = CreateUser("MrX", MrXRole, "Test1234!");  // Adds the ApplicationUser "MrX" to DBContext
        MrYRole = CreateRole("MrYRole");                // Adds the ApplicationRole "MrYRole" to DBContext
        MrY = CreateUser("MrY", MrYRole, "Test1234!");  // Adds the ApplicationUser "MrY" to DBContext

        DBContext.SaveChanges();

        var test1 = DBContext.Users.Count();            // test1 = 2  --> as expected
        var test2 = AppUserManager.Users.Count();       // test2 = 0  --> not expected --> different DBContext
    }
}
```

`test2` probably has a different DB context. When I debug, I don't see the two previously created users in the AppUserManager context. In the DbContext they are there.

I really hope someone could help me out here as I invested a lot of time on this without any success

Answer (score 0):

Could fix this on my own :)
The clue is that the `ServiceProvider` is built multiple times when calling `serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()`.
So each `ServiceProvider` has different `DBContext`.

```cs
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

DBContext = serviceProvider.GetService<DBContext>();

AppUserManager = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

AppRoleManager = serviceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
```